# Unity 3D VR (5.6), How to detect object using GVR Pointer Physic Raycaster?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

My Vr project is like a quiz using 3d object as choices, so i already made a working click event and im using GVR Pointer Physic Raycaster, but the problem is i dont know how i can get object name using GVR Pointer Physic Raycaster.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class spawn : MonoBehaviour {

    //
    int buatrandom;
    int jumlahrandom = 16 ;

    int objek1 ;
    int objek2 ;
    int objek3 ;

    int checkobjek;
    int checkobjekawal;

    string simpan1;
    string simpan2;
    string simpan3;

    public GameObject target1;
    public GameObject target2;
    public GameObject target3;

    public int [] simpannomorobject ;
    public GameObject[] nomorasset;

    public float speed =10f;
    public float berat = 1.0f;

    private gerak coba;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        simpannomorobject = new int[3]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            buatrandom = Random.Range (0, jumlahrandom);
            simpannomorobject [i] = buatrandom;
            if (i > 0){
                if (i < 3) {
                    buatobjek ();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void buatobjek (){
        objek1 = simpannomorobject [0];
        objek2 = simpannomorobject [1];
        objek3 = simpannomorobject [2];

        simpan1 = objek1.ToString();
        simpan2 = objek2.ToString();
        simpan3 = objek3.ToString();

        target1 = Instantiate (nomorasset [objek1], new Vector3 (0, 0, 3.0f), Quaternion.identity);
        target2 = Instantiate (nomorasset [objek2], new Vector3 (4.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0));
        target3 = Instantiate (nomorasset [objek3], new Vector3 (-4.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0,-90,0));

        target1.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        target2.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        target3.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();


        EventTrigger eventTrigger1 = target1.AddComponent<EventTrigger> ();
        EventTrigger eventTrigger2 = target2.AddComponent<EventTrigger> ();
        EventTrigger eventTrigger3 = target3.AddComponent<EventTrigger> ();

        EventTrigger.Entry entry1 = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
        EventTrigger.Entry entry2 = new EventTrigger.Entry( );
        EventTrigger.Entry entry3 = new EventTrigger.Entry( );

        entry1.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        entry1.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { OnPointerDownDelegate( (PointerEventData)data ); } );

        entry2.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        entry2.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { OnPointerDownDelegate( (PointerEventData)data ); } );

        entry3.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        entry3.callback.AddListener( ( data ) => { OnPointerDownDelegate( (PointerEventData)data ); } );

        eventTrigger1.triggers.Add (entry1);
        eventTrigger2.triggers.Add (entry2);
        eventTrigger3.triggers.Add (entry3);

        target1.AddComponent<gerak> ();
        target2.AddComponent<gerak> ();
        target3.AddComponent<gerak> ();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        target1.transform.Rotate(0,100* Time.deltaTime,0);
        target2.transform.Rotate(0,100* Time.deltaTime,0);
        target3.transform.Rotate(0,100* Time.deltaTime,0);
    }

    public void OnPointerDownDelegate( PointerEventData data )
    {
        print (data.enterEventCamera.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get name of object detected by `PhysicRaycaster` with [`pointerCurrentRaycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-pointerCurrentRaycast.html) not `enterEventCamera`.

```
public void OnPointerDownDelegate(PointerEventData data)
{
    print(data.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, @Programmer